# New Garbage Disposal Turns on, makes a clank sound and turns off

Tags: kitchens, sink, garbage-disposal

I recently installed a new garbage disposal under my sink. it is hardwired under the sink (with an on and off button on the junction box) and there is a switch above the sink. I've tested it for leaks and there are no leaks thus far. When switch the garbage disposal on, I hear a large clank as if the motor is running and then it immediately stops. The main breaker doesn't get tripped. And the red switch on the Garbage disposal doesn't get reset either. When I turn the switch on and off in succession, it works. As if each time I switch it on, it makes the garbage disposal spin a little and when it gets enough traction, it works like normal. Sometimes that works, sometimes it doesn't.

There is no humming

Things I've done:

- Checked for leaks
- Double-checked my connection
- Checked the inside to see if there is nothing in there

Installation

- Moen GX50C Disposer Prep Series 1/2 HP Continuous Feed Garbage Disposal with Sound Reduction, Power Cord Included
- Hardwired

What could be the issue? I would be grateful for any advice.

Update 1: I took out the garbage disposal and attached the outlet plug back in and plugged it into an outlet and it works. I should've done this in the beginning to make sure it worked. So it looks like it might be something with how the wall is wired. Does anyone know what would cause this with the wiring?

Update 2: I took out the intermediate switch under the sink and attached the garbage disposal directly to the wires coming out of the wire using the outlet (Dangerous, I know). The same issue occurs.

Update 3: I went out and bought a 20AMP switch and a GFCI outlet. I replaced the on/off switch on the junction box with a GFCI outlet. Then I replaced the switch on top with the 20AMP switch. I tested that the CFCI is live but plugging it into the outlet doesn't work. But plugging it into other outlets still works.

Update 4: Turns out the GFCI was not actually on. I had to press the reset button harder and a light turned on. Now it's working!!! Thanks @JimmyFix-it!

Comment: Turning the breaker off first, can you check if something got dropped into the disposal?  "Clank" is not something I'd want to hear from my disposal.

Comment: @stdunbar I have checked. The clank is more like a clank of the garbage disposal starting up. I've even taken the disposal off and tried to start it upside down.

Comment: I would tend to suspect the switches. I am not familiar with your "on and off button on the junction box" and question why it needs to be there; I would remove it. The wall switch above is probably rated for controlling lights, rather than a 1/2HP electric motor. This is a common problem where regular light switches are installed there instead of a heavy duty switch rated for the amp draw on the disposer.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it I went out and bought a 20AMP switch and a GFCI outlet. I replaced the on/off switch on the junction box with a GFCI outlet. Then I replaced the switch on top with the 20AMP switch. I tested that the CFCI is live but plugging it into the outlet doesn't work. But plugging it into other outlets still works.

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work" do you mean that it doesn't work at all, or that it performs as previously described? Do other things work when plugged into the new GFCI and operate properly when the new switch is used?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Apologies. I made an update #4, it works now!!! Thank you so much!